# Error "Specified cast is not valid" in query

Tags: asp.net, sql

I have a funny problem. I want to execute this query, but this error happen:

"Specified cast is not valid."

Can any body help me?

here is my code:

```
 string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(connStr);
        SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand();
        sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT max(ID) FROM AddNews ", sqlconn);

        sqlconn.Open();
        int ID = ((int)sqlcmd.ExecuteScalar());
        sqlconn.Close();
```

Comment: check the return type of "sqlcmd.ExecuteScalar());"

Comment: It is exactly an integer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a case the you may not have results and the return can be null.

You better try

```
int? MaxID = sqlcmd.ExecuteScalar() as int?;
```

and check if the MaxID is not null.

Answer (score 1):

The result is cast to an int at the SQL level. The returned value will be an int, or defaulted to 0 if null.

You can use `Convert.ToInt32(sqlCmd.ExecuteScalar())` instead of (int) or `(int?)sqlCmd.ExecuteScalar() ?? 0;`

Answer (score 1):

```
you have to change as follow


int ID=int.Parse(cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `((int)value)` use `Convert.ToInt32(value)`. It will work.

Answer (score 0):

```
sqlcmd.ExecuteScalar());
```

it returns an object not an int.

try this

```
Object s= cmd.ExecuteScalar()
int x=Integer.Parse(s.ToString))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can test if your value is an int first

```
int ID;
int.TryParse(sqlcmd.ExecuteScalar(), out ID);
```